# Shortcut to make an action in xcode

Tags: xcode6

I very much need the option of clicking `';'` in xcode and have it put that at the end of the line where it is needed

for that when I press the `";"` I first need to press `"shift+enter"` to get to the end of the line

is there anything I can do/write in order for the `"shift+enter+;"` combo to be made automatically upon pressing `";"` ?

Comment: I think it's unlikely this will be possible as there are cases where you want to put a semi-colon in the middle of a line. A for-loop for example

Comment: how does eclipse do it then ?

Comment: Are you sure it does it in every situation? When you write a for loop does it just skip to the end of the line and stick a semicolon in? Xcode will auto-fix semicolons in some situations. e.g. if I type `if(a=1;)` the semicolon would be moved to the end.

Answer (score -1):

Open Xcode from menu bar --> Preferences.
Choose Key binding, then search for the key binding or the command that you want to change its shortcut.

Comment: this is not what i want, right now i have to click shift enter and then ;, i want ";" to do all steps in 1 click, changing keybindings will not fix that